# How to open the dialog when the app is terminated - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to open the dialog when the app is terminated. I do an checking the life cycle of the app with the help of the **WidgetsBindingObserver**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
      print('app is resumed');
    } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.inactive){
      print('app is inactive');
    } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.paused){
      print('app is paused');
    } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      print('app is detached');
      if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
        print('app is resumed');
      }
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => CustomDialogBox() );
    }
  }
```

Thought like when app state becomes **AppLifecycleState.detached** the app gets terminated and when the app state again becomes **AppLifecycleState.resumed** to show a dialog, but unable to do so.

Is there any different approach to acheive that?

**Edit**
This is the screen which shows when app is terminated

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
   @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
      print('app is resumed');
    } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.inactive){
      print('app is inactive');
    } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.paused){
      print('app is paused');
    } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      print('app is detached');
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
                Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
      // SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => CustomDialogBox() );
    }
  }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar()
    )
  }
}
```

The logcat

```
I/flutter ( 8810): app is inactive
I/flutter ( 8810): app is paused
I/flutter ( 8810): app is resumed
D/DecorView( 8810): onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@bc1e6a7[MainActivity]
I/flutter ( 8810): app is inactive
I/flutter ( 8810): app is paused
I/flutter ( 8810): app is detached
D/OnePlusJankManager( 8810):  Chor uploadMDM JANK_TYPE_ONCE mViewTitle = com.example.postman/com.example.postman.MainActivity--- jank level = 1
```

Comment: You can't spontaneously construct a widget an expect it to appear. Nor is there any reason to use a post frame callback. You're likely looking for the `showDialog` function.

Comment: As per your instruction i did remove the widget just added the showDIalog function, but upon detach and returning back to the app none of the states are shown

Comment: Wasn't it showing the state when you posted your question?

Comment: no it was not showing before too actually

Comment: Please show the class wrapping the methods you show. But nothing else to keep it minimal.

Comment: Print `state` in `didChangeAppLifecycleState`. Do you get anything?

Comment: Yes i did get all the states when bugging, but after when i come back from detach nothing's happening

Comment: Please share exact logs. What's printing. What's not.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `showDialog` call to when you resume the app. There may be something with flutter not building the dialog after the app has already been detached.

```dart
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
    print('app is resumed');
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.inactive){
    print('app is inactive');
  } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.paused){
    print('app is paused');
  } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
    print('app is detached');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes the dialog does is showing up when the app is resumed, but is there any other way only to show the dialog only when the app is detached and then resumed back?

Comment: @NiroopNife What do you mean? Is this triggering a dialog on startup too? If so just add a boolean to check if the app was detached. Set it true when it detaches. When you resume and you see it true, you can show the dialog and set it back to false.

Comment: Yeah right! My bad i was just blocked off getting that answer