# How to show popup dialog if app closed when receive notification in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I am building a transport application using flutter and I have reached the receiving requests section of the captain application.
How to show dialog if app closed when receive notification?
Such as Uber app: when the captain receives a new trip request, it appears to him popup dialog to accept or reject request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166434/how-to-open-the-dialog-when-the-app-is-terminated-flutter